# Alterar altura da coluna mantendo a base CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Estou tendo problemas ao aumentar gradativamente as colunas. Eu quero que o resultado seja o mesmo da imagem abaixo:
[image: coluna]

Tentei mudar a altura de cada uma, só que a base está aumentando a largura (o que não deveria acontecer):

```css
.growthInformations {
  border: solid red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.growthInformations div h1,
.growth div h3,
.growth div p {
  color: white;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.growthInformations div {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 160px;
  text-align: center;
}

.growthInformations div>p {
  background-color: green;
  height: 300px;
}

.growthInformations {
  border: solid red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.growthInformations div h1,
.growth div h3,
.growth div p {
  color: white;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.growthInformations div {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 160px;
  text-align: center;
}

.growthInformations div>p {
  background-color: green;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="growthInformations">
  <div>
    <h1>$ 100</h1>
    <h3>100 + hours</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h1>$ 150</h1>
    <h3>180 + hours</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h1>$ 200</h1>
    <h3>260 + hours</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h1>$ 250</h1>
    <h3>380 + hours</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h1>$ 300</h1>
    <h3>420 + hours</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h1>$ 350</h1>
    <h3>520 + hours</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cara basicamente no `container pai` vc tem que colocar uma altura pré-definida, pois os filhos terão uma `%` da altura do pai entende. No caso coloquei o container pai com `600px`. Depois, ainda no container pai, vc tem que colocar `align-items: flex-end;` isso vai alinhar os filho na base do container, independente da altura.

Para finalizar usando `nth-child` e `height` em `%` vc faz a "escadinha"

```
.growthInformations div:nth-child(1) {
  height: 50%;
}
```

Veja como fica:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da imagem:

```css
.growthInformations {
  border: solid red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 600px;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.growthInformations div h1,
.growth div h3,
.growth div p {
  color: white;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.growthInformations div {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 160px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.growthInformations div:nth-child(1) {
  height: 50%;
}
.growthInformations div:nth-child(2) {
  height: 60%;
}
.growthInformations div:nth-child(3) {
  height: 70%;
}
.growthInformations div:nth-child(4) {
  height: 80%;
}
.growthInformations div:nth-child(5) {
  height: 90%;
}

.growthInformations div>p {
  background-color: green;
  /* height: 300px; */
}
```

```html
<div class="growthInformations">
  <div>
    <h1>$ 100</h1>
    <h3>100 + hours</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h1>$ 150</h1>
    <h3>180 + hours</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h1>$ 200</h1>
    <h3>260 + hours</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h1>$ 250</h1>
    <h3>380 + hours</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h1>$ 300</h1>
    <h3>420 + hours</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h1>$ 350</h1>
    <h3>520 + hours</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado, meu ajudou bastante!

Comment: @AlvaroMendes se vc acha que a resposta resolveu o problema lembre-se de marca-la como. aceita nesse ícone ✓ abaixo das setinhas ao lado da resposta ;)